# editing txt file using cmd/ batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a txt file that looks like this:

```
Name,Easting,Northing,Height,Epoch
1,2666650.148,1259312.319,412.011,2024.02.12 10:30:3541
2,2666650.148,1259312.318,412.011,2024.02.12 10:31:1210
```

And I need it rearranged to that it looks like this:

```
DateTime;SensorName;CustomerName;Flags;SensorType;Unit;East;North;Height
2024.02.12 10:30;1;1;;Prism;Meter;2666650.148;1259312.319;412.011
2024.02.12 10:30;2;2;;Prism;Meter:2666650.148;1259312.318;412.011
```

- The header is fixed and can just be replaced.
- For now, I need it to be just one time, doesn't matter which one, and without seconds.
- both Names are the same `Name`, `Flags` doesn't exist, `Sensortype` and `Unit` is fixed.

I managed to do some of it, but couldnt put it together properly. My understanding of this is just from dabling around with trial and error. I can use a VBA script, but I would rather not use Excel for it. It tends to get stuck for no reasons in the middle of the night on a Sunday.

Comment: you can load the file, split it line by line in an array and then split each array value to reorder properly. Not sure this is good advice but chatgpt is pretty talented at outputting code to perform those simple tasks, just be sure to remember that it can make mistakes

Comment: We are not here to write code for you. You said that you "managed to do some of it", and we are here to help you to fix an issue with that part only. In order to do that, we expect you to [Edit] your question to include the code you want us to help you with, along with the output it is producing and all errors and debugging information. Thank you.

Comment: @compo: thank you for editing my original question to a format that is somewhat useful. For the rest of your useful insight, lets just say i didnt ask for a complete product nor do i ask you personally to do anything at all. If you have some help, like from seb to do x by using y i am very grateful. But coming at me with an attitude makes me want to delete my 4hrs account instantly.

Comment: @AlexanderMüller apparently you did not take the [tour] or read [ask] a good question when you joined.

Comment: @AlexanderMüller, where in my previous comment did I state you had asked for a complete product? Where did I even imply that you had asked me personally? Before you try to pick an argument which you cannot win, I would strongly advise that you click on the links kindly provided for you in the above comment, and consider revising your question content accordingly. Whilst some people, myself included, have on occasion made comments including or suggesting reference information, we are not a personal tutoring service, nor do we hand hold you through your programming projects.

Comment: read the colums with a `for /f` loop (with `"tokens=1-5 delims=,"`) to get the values and `echo` them in the desired format (for example `echo %%e;;Prism;Meter;%%b;%%c;%%d`) See `for /?` for details.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Here it is my advice for you about *"to do x by using y"* as you requested.

You could solve this problem via a Batch file in the way suggested by seb in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77980653/editing-txt-file-using-cmd-batch-file#comment137475379_77980653). However, you could also solve this problem in a *very different way* using my **printf.exe** version 2.11 program.

My printf.exe application is a Windows console program that is a wrapper for the well-known [printf CRT function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/printf-printf-l-wprintf-wprintf-l?view=msvc-170&redirectedfrom=MSDN), thus allowing text and formatted numeric values ​​to be displayed in the cmd.exe window. In addition, my program printf.exe also allows to perform [Reverse Polish Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) arithmetic operations on 32-bit integers and 64-bit *double* floating-point numbers using the same method and functions of the stack-based [Hewlett-Packard calculators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_calculators#Characteristics).

The new printf.exe version 2.11 also manages character string operations and allows to write scripts (*programs*) using the simplest programming scheme. The Batch file below contains a printf.exe program that solves this problem.

```
@echo off

< input.txt printf "DateTime;SensorName;CustomerName;Flags;SensorType;Unit;East;North;Height\n"  ^
   OUT          /* Show output header                   */ ^
   80 IN        /* Read input header and discard it     */ ^
   FMT{ "%%s;%%s;%%s;;Prism;Meter;%%s;%%s;%%s\n"        /* Output format */ ^
   (            /* WHILE read line                      */ ^
      80        /*    80  (max line length)             */ ^
      IN?       /*    line_read len                     */ ^
      ^<        /*    Drop len and get:                 */ ^
                /*    "Name,Easting,Northing,Height,Epoch"      */ ^
      ","       /*    line delims                               */ ^
      split1    /*    "Name" "Easting" "Northing" "Height" "Epoch" 5        Split 5 substrings      */ ^
      ^<        /*    "Name" "Easting" "Northing" "Height" "Epoch"          Drop the 5              */ ^
      0 -5 gets /*    "Name" "Easting" "Northing" "Height" "Epoch" "Epo"    Cut seconds from Epoch  */ ^
      ^<2       /*    "Name" "Easting" "Northing" "Height" "Epo"            Drop original Epoch     */ ^
      }5        /*    "Easting" "Northing" "Height" "Epo" "Name"            Roll Up Name            */ ^
      ^>        /*    "Easting" "Northing" "Height" "Epo" "Name" "Name"     Duplicate it            */ ^
      {6 {6     /*    "Name" "Name" "Easting" "Northing" "Height" "Epo"     Roll Down both Names    */ ^
      {6        /*    "Epo" "Name" "Name" "Easting" "Northing" "Height"     Roll Down Epoch         */ ^
      OUT       /*    Output result     */ ^
      ^<*       /*    Clear all data    */ ^
   :            /* REPEAT               */ ^
   )            /* ENDWHILE             */   > output.txt
```

Output:

```
DateTime;SensorName;CustomerName;Flags;SensorType;Unit;East;North;Height
2024.02.12 10:30;1;1;;Prism;Meter;2666650.148;1259312.319;412.011
2024.02.12 10:31;2;2;;Prism;Meter;2666650.148;1259312.318;412.011
```

Although it may seem complicated, the printf.exe instructions are *very simple*. HP calculator users can start writing printf.exe programs in minutes after understanding the differences and the programming scheme. You can review a larger example of a printf.exe program in the [Base64 decoder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76957821/batch-script-file-store-the-standard-output-of-decode-base64-utility-to-a-vari/76974894#76974894)

You can download the printf.exe package from [this link](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7312&p=68956#p68956)